# Что такое синонимия?

Tags: лингвистика

Что такое синонимия?

Answer (score 1):

Синонимия — тождество или близость значения разных языковых единиц. Лексические синонимы - слова, тождественные или близкие по значению. Синонимы могут отличаться оттенками значений и сферой употребления.(глаза, очи, зенки - отличаются стилевой принадлежностью, алый, красный - оттенками значения, бегемот - гиппопотам - полные синонимы.) Грамматические синонимы - грамматические обороты, которые обозначают одно и тоже разными грамматическими средствами. Например, я любовался вишневым деревом, цветущим под окном - я любовался вишневым деревом, которое цвело под окном. Переходя дорогу, сначала посмотри налево, а потом направо - Когда переходишь дорогу, сначала посмотри налево, а потом направо.